# Unable to fetch user data from mysql database

Tags: php, mysql

I am attempting to access user data from a single table in mysql in order to display it on the screen.

eg. "Logged in as 'username'."

I have followed the instructions from this [tutorial](http://thenewboston.org/watch.php?cat=11&number=141).

This is my function:

```
//create function to fetch user data (eg. username, firstname, address, etc.)

function fetchUserData($field) {

$user_id = $_SESSION['user_id'];

$query = "SELECT '$field' FROM users WHERE id = '$user_id'";
if ($query_run = mysql_query($query)) {
    if ($query_result = mysql_result($query_run, 0, $field)) {
        return $query_result;
    }
  }
}
```

And I'm calling the function like so:

```
$firstname = fetchUserData('firstname');
$surname = fetchUserData('surname');

echo 'Logged in as '.$firstname.' '.$surname.'.';
```

The `$_SESSION['user_id']` is working, I have tested it. But i am unable to collect the data (username, address, etc.) that correlates with that user's id.

Furthermore, `$query_run` is returning resource ID #7, whatever that means??

Comment: define "not working" please? what gets printed instead of username or firstname?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

change your single quotes around `$field`

```
$query = "SELECT '$field' FROM users WHERE id = '$user_id'";
```

to backticks

```
$query = "SELECT `$field` FROM users WHERE id = '$user_id'";
                 ^      ^
```

Also, you do not have `mysql_connect()` shown, so most likely you have a variable scope issue - http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php - so your query is failing as there is no connection. You can verify this by using `or die(mysql_error())` -

```
if ($query_run = mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error()) {
```

or

```
if ($query_run = mysql_query($query)) {...}
else{die(mysql_error());}
```

Comment: THANK YOU VERY MUCH!!! The backticks did the trick. It is connecting to the server, I have a separate script for that purpose :)

Answer (score 0):

```
 if ($query_result = mysql_result($query_run, 0, $field)) {
        return $query_result;
    }
```

should be

```
 if ($query_result = mysql_result($query_run, 0)) {
        return $query_result;
    }
```

or you may use

```
 if ($query_result = mysql_result($query_run, 0, "'".$field."'")) {
        return $query_result;
    }
```

add single quote to the $field